# Getting input value from a non ajax form in octobercms

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am trying to build a simple search feature. Below is my search form

```
<form  class=" my-1 col-12 col-lg-8" action="{{ 'site-search' | page }}" method="POST">
  <input name="q" class="form-control form-control-sm shadow rounded" type="search" placeholder="What are you sourcing for?" aria-label="Search">  
  <button style="display: none;" type="submit"> Search</button>
</form>
```

and then my query

```
public function onStart(){
    $search = Input::get('q');
    $this['siteSearch'] = Advert::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->get();
}
```

then to display

```
{% for siteSearch in search %}
  {{ search.title }}
{% endfor%}
```

It does not seem to get the input value because if i try something like

```
dd($this['siteSearch'] = Buy::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . 'shoes' . '%')->get());
```

It returns results matching shoes. What might be wrong here?

Comment: is that `shoes ` or `$shoes `?

Comment: sorry. 'shoes'. That is just to see if it works

Comment: `Input::all()` can you dump this and share its result when you try to post some search term `dd(Input::all());`

Answer (score 1):

Your `onStart` function is missing the `Request $request` parameter that should accompany all `POST` requests. At the top of your controller, add:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Then, redefine your function as:

```
public function onStart(Request $request)
```

Next, get your search parameter via:

```
$search = $request->input('q');
```

`Input::get()` is used to access the PHP `$_GET[]` array, but since this is a `POST` request, you need to access your form input correctly using the `Request` class.

Complete example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ExampleController extends Controller {
  public function onStart(Request $request){
    $search = $request->input('q');
    $this['siteSearch'] = Advert::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->get();
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm you posted laravel answer :) may be he wanted to do it using October-Cms

Comment: Oh, you might be right. I know that October is built on top of Laravel, but it's possible it doesn't use the `Request` approach to form submissions. Will have to wait for some feedback from them to confirm though.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple mistake.
this

```
{% for search in siteSearch %}
{{ search.title }}
{% endfor%}
```

instead of this

```
{% for siteSearch in search %}
{{ search.title }}
{% endfor%}
```